# Firefox does not display website properly on ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Tags: firefox

[image: Firefox 43.0 does not display website properly on ubuntu 14.04.3]

Please help me the following problems:

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS and Firefox 43.0. Today, when I open firefox and it doesn't display website properly as in screenshots.

I reinstalled it but the same problem still happen.
I also use chrome but it works fine.

Comment: how did you reinstalled firefox?

Comment: I reinstalled firefox using Terminal. I remove it and then reinstall but the problem still happen.